# How to persist the data in child view onGroupCollaped() in ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have A ExpandableListView With 5 groups. And the child view has some EditTexts. When ever one group is collapsed i want to save the data from the EditTexts inside the child view to a list so that i will be able to show the same data when the group is expanded.

The problem is how to fetch the data from the childview inside the onGroupCollapsed function???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than saving the data on collapsing the group, just update your list whenever a change is happening in the child view. This way you can maintain the list without worrying about collapsing the group

Comment: But this would be a heavy operation as everytime someone changes some text, we will have to update the list. and maintaining a large list would affect the performance.

Comment: Please provide your solution if you have come to one. I, too am having complications with saving data in an ExpandableListView when groups are collapsed and data is toggled/changed involuntarily.

My question on StackOverflow is similar. Take a look at my code to see what can be used for your issue if it hasn't been solved already.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392749/expandablelistview-involuntarily-toggling-checkboxes-changing-values-when-not-i

Answer (score 0):

Set up `ArrayList<ArrayList<yourObject>> myObjectMatrix;` so that you can methodically record, add, and changed values in each of your ExpandableListView children as  their own objects. This arraylist matrix can be constructed from an SQLite Database so that each time the adapter is evoked, the ExpandableListView is populated with data that is already saved for the application. In your textChangedListener for the editText in each child, you can have the data in the matrix and dataBase changed so:

1. The child's data is changed and displays a new value for the adapter right then and there.
2. Your database data is changed so that next time the view is constructed, the arraylist and ExpandableListView uses the data input from the previous application session.

Hope this helps, it did for me!